# Azure Data Factory pipelines confuse accounts for DB access

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, permission-denied

We faced the following problem:

In the same data factory we have pipeline A and pipeline B. They include Copy Data Activity (A and B). Each Copy Data Activitie linked to different Data Sets (A and B) and different SQL Linked Services (A and B) with different service accounts (A and B). All Linked Services use the same Integration Runtime (IR) to connect on premise database.

A and B Activities run Stored procedure A and B. Service account A have execute permission
for procedure A and service account B for procedure B (obviously).

But when pipelines A and B get started at the same time by timer trigger we have errors:

[*The EXECUTE permission was denied on the Stored procedure 'A'*] in pipeline A log and [*The EXECUTE permission was denied on the Stored procedure 'B'*] in pipeline B log.

When we stoped one of time triggers for each pipelines, to avoid parallel execution, everything worked fine!

I believe pipelines A and B confuse accounts in some way.

Does anyone know how to check and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the two pipelines are trying to use the same resources at the same time, due to which you are getting error.

Please try the below solutions to resolve the issue.

1. In the same pipeline, you can run Pipeline A and Pipeline B in sequence. Arrange the activities in the pipeline A to run. At the end pipeline A, add the **Execute Pipeline activity** to run the Pipeline B.

[image]

[image]

2. You can create a custom "executor" role and new user, then grant execute permissions to it. Now use this user credentials in your Pipeline B Linked Service to access the database.

In your master DB, first create a new user:

```
CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN MyLogin WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Then, in your new DB:

```
CREATE ROLE [db_executor] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

GRANT EXECUTE TO [db_executor]
GO

sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_executor', @membername = 'MyUser'
```